# Delta neutral and directional change

Tags: delta-neutral

I read everywhere that you create delta neutral positions to prevent being affected by directional change, and while I certainly agree for basic delta neutral options (a hedged vanilla for example), can't we find options that are delta neutral but not symmetrical in changes to the underlying?

Imagine your payoff is a third order polynomial, wouldn't this option be delta neutral atm without at all being immune to directional change?

Comment: Even for a vanilla delta neutral does not mean immune to directional changes. The market  price change of a vanilla includes vanna which occurs with the product $dS dI$ where $I$ is the implied vol. So vanna*$dSdI$ can be positive or negative depending on the signs. Is this what you mean? There is only one vanilla which is truly immune to directional changes in the spot price, namely the delta-hedged option where its vanna is zero.

Comment: When you say ‘symmetrical in changes to the underlying ‘ what interval are you assuming? Delta neutral implies symmetrical for an infinitesimal interval.